# TFS 2017 tests taking suspiciously long

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a TFS 2017 build definition with a "Visual Studio Test", which runs too long and causes the build to be cancelled. I would like to know why the timeout occurs, the test log is following:

`2017-08-30T10:03:21.5254342Z Passed   ReportAnalyzer_GetBlabla_SimpleTest
2017-08-30T10:26:53.4446552Z ##[debug]FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = D:\TfsBuildAgents\RmsBuild\_work\8\s\TestResults, matchPattern = *.trx, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
[...]
2017-08-30T10:26:53.4915336Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.`

So there is a passing test at 10:03 and at 10:26 a cancellation of the build (which at this point is expected).

I do not know what is happening after 10:03... any help? Should I somehow increase the verbosity? Is is possible a bogus test is running?

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.105.25910.0

The test assemblies step has the following setup:
Test Assembly `**\*Tests\**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`,
no Filters, no Settings file, no TestRun params, code coverage disabled, not running in parallel.

Comment: When you say the build is cancelled, did you mean the timeout of the build is reached. Did you set the '**build job timeout in minutes**" in the build definition? And how long will the test take when you run it locally?

Comment: The expected cancellation after 30 min is expected because it is caused by timeout set in the field you mentioned. If you are asking about the last passing test, which is ReportAnalyzer_GetBlabla_SimpleTest, then it's locally running in less than a second.

Comment: What's the type of the test you run? A basic unit test or coded ui test or others? Does the build agent run as service or in interactive mode?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the verbosity for a vNext build log, simply need to [enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) by setting `system.debug=true`

For the long time during 10:03 and at 10:26 according to the log info   `FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = D:\TfsBuildAgents\RmsBuild\_work\8\s\TestResults, matchPattern = *.trx, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False` The build agent is trying to search and get the test result.

Suggest you manually RDP to the build agent and check if the test result file is under the corresponding path. Uncheck the *Upload test attachments* option in VSTEST task and trigger the build again.

Double check the agent is running in interactive mode or not. Try to use other build agents to narrow down if the issue is related to agent or not.